# Collection View Dynamic Cell size in ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

How can I achieve this by Collection view?? I have tried sizeForItemAtIndexPath but it didn't work as i want?

Can anyone suggest me how to do it??

[image]

Edit: I have done:

```
 -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
if (indexPath.item==0)
{

     return CGSizeMake(200,200);
}
else
{

    return CGSizeMake(90,90);

}
```

and got response :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use a UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method to specify the size you want for each cell.
This method is:

**Objc:**

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

**Swift**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

  }
```

Define the CGSize you want and your cells will take width and height you define.

Your UIViewController must implement **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** Protocol

Comment: Can you post part of what you do?